# JQuery datepicker unable to navigate with keyboard when Startview changed to month or year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

JQuery datepicker is unable to navigate with keyboard when Startview changed to 1-month or 2-year. I have given the link below for reference.

[Test](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=2&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

Or is there any other plugin which i can use to navigate with keybosd when the startview changed to year.

Comment: Is this your plugin or something you found? If found, file a bug report at their github: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues

Comment: thats not mine. I found that plugin, and needed to know if there was a solution to that.

Comment: @DannyThunder do you know any plugin that i can use, to navigate with keyboard when the start view is changed to year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to change year by pressing down Ctrl and could change month with shift. Had to go through the code to find that. My Bad...